# My machine always reboot into the GRUB prompt instead of GRUB menu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub, reboot

I got a problem that is after rebooting grub CLI always appears instead of grub menu. For me the problem is not being unable to boot into any kernels (it is simple: type exit and enter twice do the job and the grub menu reappear). What I want is to boot into grub menu instead of CLI. Is there any way to fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with GRUB2.

Comment: Once you boot, run **`sudo update-grub`**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue apart from that it was booting not at all.
Reason: My *fresh* install of Ubuntu 18.04, 17.10 and Mate 18.04 had all put the wrong `uuid` in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`.

### Version 1  (grub-cmd):

From grub shell, find root folder by peeking into the outputs of `ls` (e.g. `ls (hd0,gpt2)/`) and make sure to know on which partition your system was installed! For me, it was `sda2` since `ESP` is recommended to be the first.

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-number-generic root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-number-generic
boot
```

If booting is successful now, you can get your `uuid`'s (not `partuuid`) by typing `blkid` and verify that the correct one is noted in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`.

For me:

```
search.fs_uuid <uuid> root hd0,gpt2
...
```

### Version 2  (install-stick):

If you happen to have a bootable linux-stick, you can also boot that, mount your `ESP` and change the `uuid` there:

```
# Create folder to mount ESP
mkdir /tmp/esp

# Mount ESP (assuming sda1) to esp
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/esp

# Get UUID's of devices
sudo blkid

# Ensure correct `uuid` is set in `/tmp/esp/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`

reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue of booting into the grub command line prompt instead of the boot loader menu. In my case I was trying to boot into Linux and the problem was that after reformatting the Linux partition, an older `ubuntu` folder was left in the EFI partition (in the `EFI` folder) - even after I deleted its entry from the EFI boot list - and the UEFI was booting that old entry instead of the new one that had the correct Linux partition UUID.

The first thing to know - the GRUB command prompt isn't that scary. If you know your way around a Linux shell, GRUB isn't a problem - you basically want to load a GRUB configuration file that exists somewhere on your drive, using the `configfile` command, and you can find it using the `ls` command. The main difference from a Linux shell, is that there's a special syntax to access a drive and partition:

1. use just `ls` to list the drives.
2. Pick the correct drive, likely the first, it should be named `hd0`, and list its partitions using `ls (hd0)`.
3. Pick the correct partition - in my case it was the 6th GPT partition - and list it, for example: `ls (hd0,gpt6)`.
4. This should show you the content of the partition and you can list folders inside it using (for example) `ls (hd0,gpt6)'/boot'`
5. After locating the `grub.cfg` file, load it (for example) like so: `configfile (hd0,gpt6)'/boot/grub/grub.cfg'`, and that should show the familiar boot menu and you can run your OS from there.

In my case the permanent solution was to remove the old `EFI/ubuntu` directory from the EFI partition and set the UEFI boot order correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You say you can get into your Ubuntu install, so it should be simple enough to update/reinstall grub and see if that fixes the issue.

First, try simply using `sudo update-grub` if you haven't already, then reboot to check if that fixed it.

If this doesn't work, try manually reinstalling it with `sudo grub-install /dev/sd##` (replace ## with the current location of grub). This should be enough to reset any files that might be causing your issue.

Note: if you customized your grub install originally, this may reset those changes.